# get count of multiple values of an array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to perform a search in mongodb and nodejs which will return the count of ids that I will provide.

my collection is a log table

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc"),
    "DeviceId" : "abcd1234",
    "AppType" : "web",
    "UserId" : "5836cb01f8462cbc6d0caff8",
    "ArticleId" : "5836cb01f8462cbc6d0caff8",
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T11:37:27.851Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836dba8a2943528448a3050"),
    "DeviceId" : null,
    "AppType" : null,
    "UserId" : null,
    "ArticleId" : 5836e493f2acbd1d34648e78,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T12:23:04.484Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836e445c3b43429b4810ad4"),
    "DeviceId" : null,
    "AppType" : null,
    "UserId" : null,
    "ArticleId" : 5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T12:59:49.820Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836e493f2acbd1d34648e78"),
    "DeviceId" : null,
    "AppType" : null,
    "UserId" : null,
    "ArticleId" : 5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T13:01:07.030Z")
}
```

and so on...

my search string will be, **search need to be performed on ArticleId**

```
{"5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc", 
"5836e493f2acbd1d34648e78", 
"5836dba8a2943528448a3050"}
```

and I want a result set like below

```
{
"1":{ArticleId:"5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc", count:2}, 
"2":[ArticleId:"5836e493f2acbd1d34648e78", count:9}, 
"3":[ArticleId:"5836dba8a2943528448a3050", count:35}
}
```

Can any one please provide me the query, thanks in advance

Comment: `_id` is supposed to be unique so I don't get what kind of count do you want.

Comment: Sorry, Updated my question... please suggest

Comment: I see. Is that `"1"` , `"2"`, `"3"` necessary in the result?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you realize, but all of your counts will be 1.

That's because every `_id` in Mongo is unique so if it's there then it's there only once.

Also, the output that you want is invalid:

```
 { 1:{_id:ObjectId("5836d0f7f8462cbc6d0caffc"), count:2}, 
   2:{ObjectId("5836e493f2acbd1d34648e78"), count:9}, 
   3:{ObjectId("5836dba8a2943528448a3050"), count:35}}
```

It's not valid JSON, not valid JavaScript, not valid Hjson, not valid JSON5, not valid anything - so you will never be able to get that result no matter what you do. (And also, if you change the expected output, every `count` will still be `1` so fixing the format is pointless anyway.)

Comment: sorry my mistake... I am editing my question, please suggest